# ember-cli-htmlbars plugins not processing in-repo addon templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, htmlbars, ember-addon

I'm using a plugin for `ember-cli-htmlbars` in an addon to process the template ASTs. It works correctly for templates in my **addon's dummy application**.

However, the dummy application has an in-repo addon that contains templates in `addon/templates/`. The in-repo addon specifies `ember-cli-htmlbars` inside of its `package.json`, which causes the templates to compile correctly -- with the exception of not being passed through the plugin I have registered in the parent addon. The end result is that in-repo addon templates are not being processed by my plugin, which is ultimately fatal to my addon at runtime.

How can I cause the in-repo addon's templates to also be processed using the `ember-cli-htmlbars` plugin I specified in my addon?

Answer (score 0):

One way to "fix" this is to also register the same plugin within the in-repo addon itself -- with one special difference. While this works, it feels like the wrong thing to do.

The special difference is that you need to register plugins using `this.registry` rather than the registry from `app` or `parentAddon` inside of the `included` addon hook. Otherwise, you're just modifying registry of a thing that isn't going to compile your templates.